# MergExtDropBox Livecode Can't find handler

Tags: ios, dropbox, livecode

Trying to use MergExtDropBox for the first time in Livecode for iOS.  I've copied the external into the Copy Files pane but I'm getting a "Can't Find Handler" error when I try to run mergDropboxSetup.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that there's some issue with the way you have added the external to your app. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFTsVu7_QOI) video where I explain how to do that

---

EDIT

Based on the comments I'm not sure this is the most likely issue. I'm wondering if you are executing the command on desktop instead of iOS? If that's the problem then you will need to wrap your code in something like this:

```
if the platform is "iPhone" then
  mergDropboxSetup ...
end if
```

Comment: Thanks Monte.  I had a look at the video and I noticed that other than the .lcext file and the pre-5.5.2 subfolders there was nothing else in the zip file.  I was also wondering if there should be any plugins coming up in Livecode (there are no mergExt plugins listed).

Comment: No plugins are required for mergExt externals. What version of LiveCode are you running and are you adding mergDropbox.lcext on the copy files pane.

Comment: Ok, where are you seeing the can't find handler error? Could you take a screenshot and edit your post with it.

Comment: This one seems to be my fault.  I thought I could test on the development environment.  When I run the simulator there is no issue as far as I can tell.  Thank you for your help.